# How often should players be advancing?

Tags: apocalypse-world, character-advancement

My players are advancing at a rate of about once every one to two sessions. Is this normal, or am I being too nice with more often than not highlighting their major stat?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My character right now advances every, oh, 2-3 sessions, with an occasional 4- or 5-session lull when I'm hanging back and letting other characters take the spotlight. We play 2-hour sessions, though, so if you're playing 4-hour sessions, advancing every 1-2 sessions is about the same.

If you want to slow down - and you might not! - my recommendation is to play out more conversations, not to mess with how you've been highlighting stats.

When I MC, I always make sure that every character has at least one high stat highlighted.

Comment: By high stat do you mean their primary stat or just a stat >= 1? Also, my players seem to have for various reasons almost consistently got Sharp highlighted, which means that in conversations they leap to Read.

Comment: Oh, either way. As MC, "try to set the pace at which the PCs advance" isn't your job. Highlight their stats just by what you think is most interesting, as a giant fan of the character in question, and let it run!

Comment: Vincent's definately got it right there (.. though that perhaps shouldn't be surprising.)  My characters were advancing far quicker than I expected, but we all had a ball so I don't tend to worry about being too "nice".  AW isn't like D&D, where character "power-ups" are part of the game reward... the characters start bad-ass and the game is all in the story.